# Simple module that displays a template on every single page

Tags: extensions, blocks, template

I'm very new to magento development. I got stuck on creating a template or block extension that shows some `php` on every single page if you're logged in and an admin.

I got the block working (I think) and i make a test.php page to test it and it worked fine.

My `blockdesign.php` file:

```
class McDefault_locationreminder_Block_Blockdesign{
    private $content;
    private $loco;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->content = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $this->loco = 'local';//TODO: Fetch from db
    }

    public function showBlock(){
        echo '<div class="reminder">'.$this->loco.': '.$this->content.'</button></div>';
    }
}
```

The `test.php` file:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$product = new McDefault_locationreminder_Block_Blockdesign;
$product->showBlock();
```

[image: a busy cat]

Now the only part is to made it a template and show on all pages (as admin).

This is where i need help because i have no clue on where to create all these `xml` files or `phtml` files.

I need help with the path to create these files and the content of them.
namespace is McDefault and name is locationreminder.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper way of creating a block in magento. The right way is the "module" way and you can find an ***[example here](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/MagentoStackExchange_Helper/tree/Rkt_CustomBlock)***.

If you want to see the block which is creating by the above module in every page, then you need to do a small modification in the below file

File : `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\rkt_customblock.xml`

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="rkt_customblock/helloworld" name="myblock.helloworld" template="rkt_customblock/helloworld.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

It is very important understand the "flow" that happens here. Unfortunately it is too broad to explain here. There are lot of tutorials available for this. However you can use ***[this one](http://www.rktinaction.com/magento/hello-world-module)*** to get an idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check your links out.

Comment: I got most of it working, except for one thing. The block displays on only the frontend. I'd like it to show in the admin panel too. Any idea how that is done?